# How to check if child process is still running?

Tags: python, timestamp, multiprocessing, verification

For security reasons I need to check on a reoccurring basis if a child process is still alive. I spawned it like this:

```
NdeProc = Process(target=NodeRun, args=(NodeQ,))
NdeProc.start()
```

And I really only want to check in my main process if the "NodeRun" is still going? I haven't found anything in the docu yet and thought I might need to do a timestamp file in which I'd keep updating a timestamp from the child process and the parent process could just check it but I was wondering if there's a better method somone could come up with?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`is_alive()`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.is_alive) for this:

```
if NdeProc.is_alive():
    ...
else:
    ...
```

From the documentation:

> Return whether the process is alive. Roughly, a process object is alive from the moment the start() method returns until the child process terminates.